# Micelles Sticking Together

Tags: digestion

I have a quick question regarding micelles. I have tried googling the answer but can't seem to find the answer. The question is, during digestion lipids are emulsified into micelles in order to increase their surface area for digestion but my question is, why don't the micelles stick together and form a clump which would decrease it's surface area?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micelles have a hydrophobic core and a polar, hydrophilic surface. This surface will preferentially associate with water molecules and become solvated, rather than sticking to lipids.

Negative charge on phospholipids at the micelle surface mediate electrostatic repulsion to other micelles, keeping them from sticking together.